# Capacitor calculation

Tags: power, capacitor, fuses

I am new to the concept of pyro-fuses, if the firing current is 1.2A/2ms, this means that I need to provide at least 1.2A for 2ms for the pyro to be triggered. Now if I want to use a capacitor to provide this firing pulse for a 2-3 Ohm load, how to calculate how much capacitance needed? The calculations I am getting don't make sense, and I am not sure if I understood the concept correctly.

Comment: What starting voltage on the capacitor are you willing to consider?

Comment: I think similar question was just asked. Show how you did the calculations, they may be correct, and thus the result will be that the capacitor values required are not sensible, which will also means, capacitor is not a sensible solution to the problem.

Comment: I am trying work with a minimum voltage of 3.6V for the worst case. I also asked the same question earlier and it was deleted for some reason and I saw some questions about energy storage caps but I don't know whether it is applicable for a squib as well. I am not sure if this is the correct formula for this purpose but I am using I=I0exp(−t/RC). I=1.2A, I0=3.6/2, t=2ms, R=2ohm

Comment: @404 At 3.6 V and assuming worst case of 3 Ohms, the fact is that you cannot get there from here. It would take precisely infinite Farads to deliver that energy in 2 ms (if I didn't make a mistake.) I would not assume 2 Ohms if it is possible that they are also 3 Ohms, sometimes. Did I read you wrong, there?

Comment: Yes you're right, so this basically means that the whole approach is wrong and a cap is not a solution right?

Comment: @404 No, I wouldn't say that. I would say I don't know enough about your application. For example, is this to be delivered through some very long wire?

Comment: @404 Spec is \$2\:\Omega-3\:\Omega\$. Take larger as conservative. Work is \$W=2\:\text{ms}\cdot\left(1.2\:\text{A}\right)^2\cdot 3\:\Omega=8.64\:\text{mJ}\$, delivered in \$2\:\text{ms}\$. Energy on cap is \$E=\frac12C\,V_0^2\$. The ratio \$\rho=\frac{W}{E}\$ must be less than 1. \$t=-\frac12R\,C\ln\left(1-\rho\right)=2\:\text{ms}\$. As \$\rho\to 1\$, \$R\,C\$ must be shorter so smaller \$C\$ and higher starting \$V_0\$. For lower \$V_0\$, \$\rho\ll 1\$. But that means excess energy storage on \$C\$ that won't be used up in \$2\:\text{ms}\$. Don't know if that's okay & don't know about wire.

Comment: @404 You need to write more.

Comment: @404 - You said: "*I also asked the same question earlier and it was deleted for some reason*" FYI the audit log shows that it's *you* who deleted your earlier question. || As site members may know, "delete & repost" of the same question is not allowed. However the focus of this question appears just different enough to the previous one, that posting it as a new question seems reasonable. Also there was no analysis in comments on the first question which was lost by deleting it.

Comment: @SamGibson thank you for clarifying, I wasn't aware of that, during the editing thought it was because of the rule compliance, I will be more careful then

Comment: @periblepsis basically negligeable wire resistance

Comment: @404 I think you can pick stuff off from [this parametric plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oew2B.png). The x-axis is \$\rho\$. You may easily see here that near \$\rho=1\$, you can get by with rapidly shrinking capacitor values but at the same time the voltage goes through the roof. As soon as you move even slightly to the left from there, the size of the capacitor moves quickly into milliFarads but then the voltage flattens out. I don't see 3.6 V happening. But a little more could work.

Comment: Thank you very much @periblepsis

Comment: @404 No problem. Hope it helps. I spotted that \$1500\:\mu\text{F}\$ and \$4.5\:\text{V}\$, around \$\rho=0.6\$, could be a choice made. This means that only 60% of the stored energy would be applied in \$2\:\text{ms}\$. That may mean you throw away the other 40%. But that's not necessarily bad.

Answer (score 1):

C=I*t/U. So you would need 2.4mF per Volt or 0.66mF at 3.6V.

Comment: Just to clarify - you are using SI units and "mF" means **milli**-Farads and not **m**icro-Farads aren't you?

Comment: Yes, all SI style.

Answer (score 0):

I also new to the concept of Pyro fuse, but based on information,I found the relate document from [here](https://hal.science/hal-01361696/document).

> Rémy Ouaida, Jean Francois de Palma, Gilles Gonthier. Hybrid Protection based on Pyroswitch and
> Fuse Technologies for DC Applications. Symposium de Genie Electrique, Jun 2016, Grenoble, France.
> ffhal-01361696

That gave the deffinition of Pyro-fuse as the device that combine Pyro-switch and fuse in parallel.

The Pyro-switch is the switch that use Pyro-technique chemical in cut through the busrbar, result in high voltage, high current fast response cut-off switch. to trigger it, it require some energy to ignite the chemical.

The paralleled fuse is under rated and be there to keep low voltage across pyro-switch then it will opened afterward.

In sumarized, the pyro-fuse is safty cut-off switch that work on external trigger which required amount of current in some specific duration to start the action.

For application and designs, I found this [application note](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an5754-l9680-cutoff-battery-and-pyro-fuse-stmicroelectronics.pdf) document from TI called "L9680 Cut-off Battery and Pyro Fuse" and the [L9680 Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l9680.pdf)
and this application circuit is quit interesting.

[image]

This figure show that "Energy reserve capacitor" which get charge by using 5V or 3V3 power with boost converter to 25V or 33V (Programmable) the BOM of application circuit from datasheet required min 2.2mF to 4.7mF maximum. This design for deploy with 1.25A or 1.75A current to pyroswitch.

However, both of the application note and datasheet doesn't shown the calculation or rules to select the value of capacitor.

The correct answer will depend on the circuit and scinario of usage. For example le assumed that I just use the switch to discharge the capacitor to pyroswitch from fully charge cap.
The pyroswitch required 1.2A for 2ms with resistance of 2.5Ohms
the minimum voltage to get 1.2A is IxR =  3V

Then for RC discharge voltage equation

Vc = Vs*exp(-t/(R*C))

then solve this equation and we got

C = 1/(1250*log(Vs/3))

As it depend on fully-charge of capacitor then let assumed it tobe 5V
We got C = 0.00156609 or about 1.56609 mF, don't forget to consider safety factor, ESR and wire resistance.